# How to work with dynamic content

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel, xib

I am working with a UITable View and I am trying to figure out the best way to handle the way I display the content as its dynamic.

For instance some of the things I search may have a title and a description but then other times only have a title.

In a n instance like this I would like to be able to control the positioning of the labels in my UITableCell, of which I have created a custom one.

For instance this is a graphical view of what I am trying to do.

**Title:**

[image]

**No Title:**

[image]

As you can see with the second option I have decided to move the UILabel to the left where the Title label would be.

So What would be the best way of doing this?
I am thinking maybe creating several different format types in a .xib and then just using if statments.. if its missing such and such then use cell a or b or c.

Or is there a better way to achieve this?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different formats in .xib files will do the trick, just instance the proper cell type according to your needs, the other is delving into how you draw your cells, adding labels as you see fit when you get your data and drawing them appropriately.

Comment: Okay cool.. was just checking I guess as I havent done anything like this so wasn't sure if my idea was correct.